# Why does the MSVC 10.0 compiler often ignores the inline keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inlining

I have some quite complex c++ code which is used in a real-time system and is thus absolutely speed sensitive. It was developed on Linux and to speed it up a lot of functions were marked with the "inline" keyword and moved into header files to allow inlining.

Now I ported this code to Windows (msvc 10.0, Windows 7) and it runs about 30% slower. After doing some profiling I found out that the problem is basically that a lot of functions are not inlined. When I use "__forceinline" instead, I easily see a speed-up around 10-20%.

Does anybody has an explanation for this? Is it only that the algorithm in msvc works far more conservatively? Or did I just do something wrong, like missing an configuration option?

Comment: Seems like MSVS fails to see the benefit in inlining the code. Not much more to it.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Answer (score 5):

You need to check your MSVC optimization settings:

```
Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization
```

There's a setting called `"Favor size or speed"` which substantially alters how much inlining the compiler is prepared to do.

Answer (score 4):

> What is `inline` ?

`inline` is a keyword that signals to the compiler that the method definition is presented inline. Normally, a method should only be defined in a single TU (source file, roughly), and `inline` allows one to define a method in a header, which will be included in many different TUs, and avoid the compiler/linker complaints about *duplicate symbols*. The linker will merge the symbols appropriately.

> What is **not** `inline` ?

`inline` is by no mean an order for the compiler to inline the function. Historically it may have been used as such, but optimizers have gotten better and better at deciding when to (and not to) inline, and the `inline` "hint" has little effect nowadays.

> How to enforce inlining ?

Compilers usually provide specific keywords/attributes to require "more" inlining. In MSVC for example, `__forceinline` will hint *strongly* (but still just hint) that the method should be inlined.